# Robust Expectation-Maximization?

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, inference, expectation-maximization, robust

The Expectation-Maximization (EM) algorithm is useful for applying the Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) when there exist latent (hidden) variables in the model. However, when dealing with outliers, the expectation (mean) is not robust statistics.

Now for MLE, we can use M-estimators to reduce the effect of outliers which can be used in the M-step (maximization). My question is if there is a robust alternative for the E-step (expectation) in the EM algorithm?
I'm interested in both mathematical and empirical alternatives.

Comment: Robust regression with Huber or Tukey loss functions works quite well for filtering outliers. I am not sure however, why EM could be sensitive to the outliers: separating mixture of the inliers from the outliers is precisely the point.

Comment: While no alternative, I would assume that you can show reasonable properties by "robustifying" the Expectation Step -- it's a mean computation problem.